# Create a Synthetic Vision System

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, heightmap

I would like to add this feature to my android app:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_vision_system

In short it I believe it is a terrain heightmap.  I specifically need help with rendering the terrain.  The rest of the display I can accomplish.

After a day of google I appear to be no closer.   My research seems to point to using opengl, heightmaps and SRTM. However I have no clue how to tie it all together.   None of the java examples are android specific.

Alternatively maybe using openstreetmaps and a tile overlay but I cant establish if it is possible in 3D.

The app will be a moving map based on GPS position of the aircraft.  As the aircraft moves over the earth the terrain ahead will be updated.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can create terrain with native java code in android studio or eclipse maybe it's very complicated if there's no such sdk available. But you can do one thing, create terrain in Unity3D game engine and then convert project into android studio project, then you can make rest changes in studio as you want

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand something but this system builds the synthetic environment so it has not usual camera. How do u want make it on simple phone? Will you connect external modules|devices?

Comment: Generate a simple terrain is very easily! But to fast generate a realistic terrain you need use a lot of optimizations. I need a more details to advice something you

Comment: @ghostman I will update the question,  however the app will be a moving map based on the aircraft's position.  No there will be no connection to external modules.

Comment: Well, you already have the map so you don't need to generate terrain just build it from map data. How will you save a map data?

Comment: @ghostman,  thanks for your help.  Unfortunately I don't know how to display the map in 3d.  Google maps which I have use in the past does not seem to support this type of display.  Neither does Openstreetmaps.  So how do I display the terrain in an activity?

Comment: @Reafidy, you can draw it everywhere :) E.g. Inkscape, CorelDraw and etc, and etc. But you don't need to make it manually, use raster maps and trace it to vector with editions. Maybe, you can find already built vector maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend you to use a vector format with few layers. For example, layer of depth, layer of landscape type and layer of objects. To build 3D from this data you need to divide the map in small tiles and load data in memory for visible area only. Your 3D builder will parse this data. E.g. a simple renderer (using OpenGL)... You create mesh as large as tile size and with enough count of vertexes. Next, you parse depth layer and move each vertex along Z-axis like it need. After you need to set color like it specified in type layer. And finally, you need create and locate objects like object layer data (it's already built-in meshes). When you build needed tiles you pass it to renderer.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful,  so where does this drawing actually take place?

Comment: Imma sorry, I don't understand you

Comment: How to find tiles that you need to draw at some moment?

Comment: What I mean is I sort of understand the principle of what needs to be done, but how do you actually render the mesh in an activity/fragment?

Comment: here is the map I was thinking of using:  https://koordinates.com/layer/1418-nz-80m-digital-elevation-model/

Comment: Use `GLSurffaceView` if you want use java but performance will awful. So, it will better to use Android NDK and write it using native activity with OpenGL. Also you can combine `GLSurfaceView` with native randerer.

Comment: Ok, its getting a little clearer now thanks.   When you are talking about dividing the map into small tiles, which map are you referring too?

Comment: Yeah, you can use it. But you need to processing it before using

Comment: Are there any code samples?  I'm not sure I'm using the right search terms!

Comment: Sorry, if I'll explain you all in details I'll write a book here. :) The best variant to tile size will be flexible (your builder must work with any tile size). Dimensions of tiles depend from height of view and tiles count from device performance and user movement speed.

Comment: Haha fair enough, thanks - you have been very helpful.  I probably need to process/research what your saying a bit more.  I thought it might have been a lot easier than this.  I thought it might be possible to simply use a tile overly over google maps or something.

Comment: This little app appears to do render terrain something similar to what I want.    Then I could just make the view move with GPS postion.  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maps3d&hl=en

Comment: If you doesn't create suit systems then you can write it very very long. It will helpful to learn this area but if you want result then use graphics engines.

Comment: As improvement of your tile mesh you can use neuronet to move vertex in XY-plane of short distance.

Comment: I have no idea what neuronet is. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112848/discussion-between-ghostman-and-reafidy).